# Error: "I/Process (26960): Sending signal. PID: 26960 SIG: 9 Lost connection to device." while using flutter on android studio

Tags: firebase, android-studio, flutter, google-maps, geolocation

After I typed in this block of code, Every time I try to run the program, I get this

"I/Process (26960): Sending signal. PID: 26960 SIG: 9

Lost connection to device.

Below is the block of code.I had added all the permission and dependencies necessary to make this work  but I'm still stuck on this error. Please assist me (I use windows).

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class HomeTabPage extends StatelessWidget
{
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controllerGoogleMap = Completer();
  GoogleMapController newGoogleMapController;

  static final CameraPosition _kGooglePlex = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.42796133580664, -122.085749655962),
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );

  Position currentPosition;
  var geolocator = Geolocator();


  void locatePosition() async
  {
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    currentPosition = position;

    LatLng intLatPosition = LatLng(position.latitude, position.longitude);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition(target: intLatPosition, zoom: 14);
    newGoogleMapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    //String address = await AssistantMethods.searchCoordinateAddress(position, context);
    //print("This is your Address :: " + address);

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        GoogleMap(
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
          myLocationEnabled: true,
          onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller)
          {
            _controllerGoogleMap.complete(controller);
            newGoogleMapController = controller;

            locatePosition();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have similar problem with using ClusterManager. Unfortunately adding android.enableDexingArtifactTransform=false did'n work. What's interesting all is good on preprod,only prod crashes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, I'm leaving this here in case anyone else is facing the same problem. I added

```
android.enableDexingArtifactTransform=false
```

to gradle.properties and it worked.

check out https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72185 for more details

Answer (score 2):

hi maybe it is because of permission access, please add this line of code to your /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Thanks but I did that already. still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make the **main function** in **main.dart** **async** it worked in my case

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).